# Validar Hora Javascript

Tags: javascript

Actualmente necesito validar la hora que viene de un input, es enviada en un formulario y la envío con el método onsubmit="return valida(this)" necesito validar varios campos pero el que me esta dando problema es que  no sea menor que la hora del servidor.

El problema que me genera es que no importa la hora que coloque siempre me dispara la alerta "La hora de la programación de la campaña no puede ser menor a la hora actual".

Cabe destacar que validé que los inputs salieran con la información correspondiente y los envia bien pero al parecer no logra detectar que hora es menor que otra.

Para ello tengo el siguiente código.

```html
<!--Validaciones LuisSerrano-->
  <script type="text/javascript">

  //Hora

  var time = new Date();
  var horals= time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric',       minute: 'numeric', hour12: true});
  var tim2 = time.getHours();
  var tim3 = tim2-12;
  var ampm='';
  var prueba = document.getElementById('hora');
  console.log(`La prueba es: ${prueba}`)
  console.log(horals);
  if (tim2>11){
    ampm = 'PM';
  }else{
    ampm = 'AM'
  }
  var fechacompleta = `${tim3}:00 ${ampm}`;


  //Fecha
  Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    let mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
    let dd = this.getDate();

    return [this.getFullYear(), mm<10 ? '0'+ mm: mm, dd<10 ? '0'+ dd : dd].join('-')
  };

  let date = new Date();
  let fecha = date.yyyymmdd();
  function valida(f) {
    let ok = true;
    let msg = "Alerta:\n";
   alert(f.elements["timepicker"].value);
   alert(horals);
    if(f.elements["fechals"].value < fecha)
    {
      msg += "- La fecha de la programación de la campaña no puede ser menor a la fecha actual\n";
      ok = false;
    }

    if(f.elements["fechals"].value == fecha && f.elements["timepicker"].value < horals )
    {
      msg += `La hora de la programación de la campaña no puede ser menor a la hora actual\n`;
      ok = false;
    }

    if(f.elements["timepicker"].value == '12:00 PM' )
    {
      msg += `RadarSystems descansa a las 12:00 PM... Programa tu campaña para despues la 1:00 PM\n`;
      ok = false;
    }

    if(ok == false)
      //alert(msg);
    swal("Error!", msg, "error");

    return ok;
  }
  </script>

  <!--Validaciones Luis Serrano-->
```

Comment: como lo veo estás comparando strings, es necesario esto ? no puedes hacerlo comparando fechas?

Comment: Fiajte que la fecha del servidor es de tipo object y la fecha que envia el input es de tipo string y sin embargo las fechas me las valida bien.

Comment: Lo que yo creo que pudiera estar pasando es que me toma por ejemplo solo la hora. Las 11 (Hora del servidor) si yo envio en el input las 1:00:pm el toma como que la 1 es menor que las 11 y no valida. Creo que debo convertir todos los pm en hora de 24H para que me pueda validar bien.

Comment: ¿Porqué trabajas de esa forma? Lo ideal es que trabajes todo con Date. Olvídate de hacer conversiones y cosas tan elaboradas. Genera un objeto Date usando los datos del cliente y compáralo con un objeto Date del servidor.

Comment: Como hago eso? :(